# Page auto-update like in Twitter

Tags: jquery, python, twitter, twisted

I wanna add page auto-update on my web site. It's written in Python and jquery, so I wanna try Twisted (or another COMET thing). The problem is about I don't know what exactly I need and what docs I have to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options for using Twisted for COMET:

1. [Orbited](http://orbited.org/)
2. [Divmod Athena](http://divmod.org/trac/wiki/DivmodNevow/Athena)

Both of these have tutorials you'll have to read and work through, which won't fit into this small answer area, but you should be able to find them fairly easily.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

use an ajax call with a setInterval, add new content - if any -  on the success function of JQuery's AJAX to the according div.